# Como recibir una imagen desde el backend al frontend?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend, frontend

Buenas noches soy nuevo en estoy y estoy haciendo una Api (con personajes de los simpsons), resulta que para la entrega me pide que se pueda cargar o modificar datos. En resumen: quiero cargar un nuevo personaje desde el frontend, llega correctamente al backend lo carga y quiero que en la res le devuelva al frontend los datos que cargo asi desde el frontend puedo abrir un modal con la foto del personaje nuevo y decir un mensaje "PERSONAJE CARGADO", desde el frontend puedo llamar a todos los datos MENOS A LA IMAGEN.
desde el back:

```
const cargarPersonaje =  (req, res)=>{ 
    const Imagen=`http://localhost:3000/ImagenPersonaje/${req.file.filename}`
    const newPersonaje=  new Personaje ({...req.body, Imagen});
      newPersonaje.save((error)=>{
        if (error){
            res.status(500).json({message: "No se pudo cargar el personaje"})
         
        }else{
            res.status(200).send(newPersonaje)
            console.log(newPersonaje);
            console.log(Imagen);
            
        }
    })
}
```

y en frontend:

```
     const Formulario = () => {
      function enviarFormulario (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData(e.target)
        const newPersonaje={
            Nombre: data.get("Nombre"),
            Historia: data.get("Historia"), 
            
            Genero: data.get("Genero"),
            Estado: data.get("Estado"),
            Ocupacion: data.get("Ocupacion"),
        };
        data.append("newPersonaje", JSON.stringify(newPersonaje));
        
        
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/personajes`,{
        method:"POST",
        /*headers:{
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type" : 'application/json' }*/
       
        
        body: data
    
        })
        .then(res=> (console.log(newPersonaje)))
          
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
```

Si pongo newPersonaje.Nombre si me sale el nombre pero si pongo newPersonaje.Imagen no lo hace

Comment: Podes mostrarnos la clase Personaje?

Comment: ¿? como la clase Personaje?

Comment: Y qué devuelve el array NewPersonaje.imagen es una URL, un Base64 ???

Comment: @PabloAlejandroAcuña 'El operador new permite a los desarrolladores crear una instancia de un tipo de objeto definido por el usuario o de uno de los tipos de objeto integrados que tiene un función constructora', de donde sacaste 'Personaje'? es una clase propia? es un objeto propio?

Comment: Personaje es un modelo que cree donde se carga personajes en mongo,  soy novato asi que agradeceria lenguaje menos tecnico